# No Signs of Fatal Exception when application crashes | NLog version 2 | Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: crash, compact-framework, windows-ce, nlog

I have a .Net Compact Framework 3.5 application that uses Nlog version 2.0 to log Info, Error and Fatal Exceptions. Most of the time the logging works as expected and logs fatal exceptions before crashing. But at times it is observed that application crashes without leaving any signs of an error/exception.

Let me elaborate the scenario:

> 1. The Application creates few threads, all the threads have try-catch block added at the beginning of their call stacks. And hence log fetal
>      exceptions before crashing.
> 2. The main thread have 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException' to log any fetal exceptions on its call stack.
> 3. The application does load some third party managed dlls and performs some PInvokes on Wnce dlls.

But I believe even if some third party DLL crashes (or let’s say it creates a new thread which crashes), I should at least see some `ThreadAbortExceptions` in the log, logged by my application's thread before exiting.

The key configuration parameters of Nlog are:

> a. FileTarget.AutoFlush = true
>
> b. FileTarget.KeepFileOpen= false
>
> c. FileTarget is not wrapped in any async wrapper or in any buffered
>   wrapper.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. If you have additional information or want to make changes, use the "Edit" link instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for the crash include OutOfMemory exception or StackOverflowException.  From the [documentation for the latter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx):

> Version Considerations
>
> In prior versions of the .NET Framework, your application could catch a StackOverflowException object (for example, to recover from unbounded recursion). However, that practice is currently discouraged because significant additional code is required to reliably catch a stack overflow exception and continue program execution.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default. Consequently, users are advised to write their code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example, if your application depends on recursion, use a counter or a state condition to terminate the recursive loop. Note that an application that hosts the common language runtime (CLR) can specify that the CLR unload the application domain where the stack overflow exception occurs and let the corresponding process continue. For more information, see ICLRPolicyManager Interface and Hosting Overview.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My application is running on Compact Framework 3.5.
I tried emulating both the conditions on a separate thread. 

For Out of memory exception, I did get  System.OutOfMemoryException on the thread where I had written the code and on other threads I got System.Threading.ThreadAbortException. This was logged in application logs. 

And yes, for StackOverFlow exception there are no logs.