# Silent application crash

Tags: crash, compact-framework, silent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No Signs of Fatal Exception when application crashes | NLog version 2 | Compact Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730716/no-signs-of-fatal-exception-when-application-crashes-nlog-version-2-compact)

I have a .Net Compact Framework 3.5 application which uses Nlog to log Fatal Exceptions. Most of the time the logging works as expected and logs fatal exceptions before crashing. But at times its observed that application crashes without leaving any signs of an error/exception. 
Let me elaborate the scenario -

1. The Application creates few threads, all the threads (normal, threadpool, APMs, timer) have try-catch block added at the beginning of their call stacks. And hence log fatal exceptions before crashing.
2. The main thread have 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException' to log any fatal exceptions on its call stack.
3. The application does load some third party managed dlls and performs some PInvokes on Wnce dlls. 
   But I believe even if some third party dll crashes (or lets say it creates a new thread which crashes), I should at least see some ThreadAbortExceptions in the log, logged by my application's thread before exiting.
4. The behavior is sporadic and, at times, happens within some time after starting the application.
5. There are no Application.DoEvents in the code.

What all could be possible reasons for such a crash ? Why are there absolutely no exceptions in the logs ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.